# Logstash to load input file based on time change

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash

I'm using Logstash 7.17.0, in that i'm trying to load file using pipeline.
It is taking file based on size or checksum changes, but i wanted to pick the file even if the size same but change in file timings.

For example: i'm getting data everyday, in some cases i might get the same data like yesterday. But logstash is not picking the file if the size is same.

Answer (score 0):

Logstash tracks the current position in watched files in a dedicated file named `sincedb` ([docs](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-inputs-file.html#_tracking_of_current_position_in_watched_files)). If you disable this feature, Logstash will always read the entire file from the beginning. To do so, you can set to `/dev/null` the [sincedb_path](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-inputs-file.html#plugins-inputs-file-sincedb_path) property of the `file` input plugin, e.g.,

```
input {
  file {
    path => "/path/to/your/file"
    sincedb_path => "/dev/null"
  }
}
```

Comment: I have used the option, but if same file comes it is not all picking up and loading it

Comment: What do you mean that the same file comes?

Comment: Same file with same file size and checksum on the day 2